# Spring Cloud custom post filter unable to get the response body

Tags: spring, filter, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Able to have response in postman,
But in custom Post Filter able not to log the response;

`log`

```
response1
response5
```

`apply` Method

```
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(ResponsePostFilter.Config config) {

        return new GatewayFilter() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
                System.out.println("response1");

                ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();

                DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();


            ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = getDecoratedResponse(response, dataBufferFactory);
//                System.out.println("response4");

           


                return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build())
                        .onErrorResume(err -> {
                            log.error("Error while decorating Response: {}", err.getMessage());
                            return Mono.empty();
                        });
            }
            public ServerHttpResponseDecorator getDecoratedResponse(ServerHttpResponse response , DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory) {
                System.out.println("response5");
                return new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {



                    @Override
                    public Mono<Void> writeWith(final Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                        System.out.println("response2");

                        if (body instanceof Flux) {
                            System.out.println("response3");
                            Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
                            return super.writeWith(fluxBody.buffer().map(dataBuffers -> {
                                        DefaultDataBuffer joinedBuffers = new DefaultDataBufferFactory().join(dataBuffers);
                                        byte[] content = new byte[joinedBuffers.readableByteCount()];
                                        joinedBuffers.read(content);
                                        String responseBody = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);//MODIFY RESPONSE and Return the Modified response
                           log.info(" statusCode: {}  MyInfoResponse body: {}",response.getStatusCode(), responseBody);

                            return dataBufferFactory.wrap(responseBody.getBytes());
                        })
                            ).onErrorResume(err -> {
                            log.error("Error while decorating Response: {}", err.getMessage());
                            return Mono.empty();
                        });
                    } else {
                        //Do nothing
                        }
                        return super.writeWith(body);
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        };
```

Comment: able to find a solution:

Reference link: https://github.com/einsteinarbert/spring-webfux-response-logging/blob/master/gateway-service-filter-properties/src/main/java/com/javainuse/config/GatewayCustomFilter.java